# python 3 unable to write to file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, attributeerror

My code is:

```
from random import randrange, choice
from string import ascii_lowercase as lc
from sys import maxsize
from time import ctime

tlds = ('com', 'edu', 'net', 'org', 'gov')

for i in range(randrange(5, 11)):
    dtint = randrange(maxsize)                      
    dtstr = ctime()                                  
    llen = randrange(4, 8)                              
    login = ''.join(choice(lc)for j in range(llen))
    dlen = randrange(llen, 13)                          
    dom = ''.join(choice(lc) for j in range(dlen))
    print('%s::%s@%s.%s::%d-%d-%d' % (dtstr, login,dom, choice(tlds),
                                  dtint, llen, dlen), file='redata.txt')
```

I want to print the results in a text file but I get this error:

```
dtint, llen, dlen), file='redata.txt')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`file` should be a file object, not a file name. File objects have `write` method, `str` objects don't.

From the doc on [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

> The *file* argument must be an object with a `write(string)` method; if it
>   is not present or `None`, `sys.stdout` will be used.

Also note that the file should be open for writing:

```
with open('redata.txt', 'w') as redata: # note that it will overwrite old content
    for i in range(randrange(5,11)):
        ...
        print('...', file=redata)
```

See more about the `open` function [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).